# Using MINLOC with Fortran: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment

Tags: arrays, fortran

### Version that gives an error message

```
program hello
   integer a(9)
   integer index; ! note no dimension here
   a=(/1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10/)
   index = MINLOC(a, MASK=(a > 5))
   Print *, index
end program Hello
```

### Error message

main.f95:5.3:

index = MINLOC(a, MASK=(a > 5))
   1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)

### Working version

```
program hello
   integer a(9)
   integer index(1) ! note dimension 1 here which looks redundant at first
   a=(/1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10/)
   index = MINLOC(a, MASK=(a > 5))
   Print *, index
end program Hello
```

### Search

[Here](http://morecakelessfish.blogspot.com.au/2008/12/incompatible-ranks.html) I could find related discussion but I don't find it sufficiently verbose for me to understand the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fix the first version, obtaining a scalar return from `minloc`, by using the `DIM` argument:

```
index = MINLOC(a, DIM=1, MASK=(a > 5))
```

P.S.  No need for semicolons to end statements unless you place multiple statements per line.  Fortran isn't C.

Comment: Removed semicolons; they were added accidentally when trying to troubleshoot another error message...

Comment: Got through this answer, nicely tougth. Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

[This discussion](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=680133) brings up an important point: MINLOC returns an array, even if it's only one number, it's still an array.

It may be possible to declare index as an array, like mentioned above, or to use a temporary array.

```
integer :: temp(1)
...
temp=minloc(dist)
index=temp(1)
```

---

It is also possible to use DIM argument to avoid manual fiddling with data types, like mentioned in M.S.B's answer.