# sorting arrays by rows in FORTRAN

Tags: arrays, sorting, fortran

I need to sort rows of a matrix in ascending/descending order. In matlab I can do quite easily as follows:

```
A=[3 1 0;2 1 9;0 4 8]
sortrows(A,1)
```

so it will sort the rows in column "1" and the other columns will follow accordingly. But I need to do this in FORTRAN. And I am not very familiar with FORTRAN. Can anyone advise me how to do this in FORTRAN. Thanks.

Comment: There is no sorting intrinsic in Fortran. You would need to write your own implementation. Sorry... However. there are several ready-to-use routine available out there in the wild ;-)

Comment: For columns you could call `qsort` from the C standard library. For rows it would be tricky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although Fortran does not have sorting intrinsics, the code may become a bit simpler if you use [minloc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MINLOC.html) function to find the smallest element in the first column and  swapping the corresponding row with the current one iteratively, for example:

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer :: A(3,3), buf(3)
    integer :: nsize, irow, krow

    nsize = 3
    A( 1, : ) = [ 3, 1, 0 ]
    A( 2, : ) = [ 2, 1, 9 ]
    A( 3, : ) = [ 0, 4, 8 ]

    do irow = 1, nsize
        krow = minloc( A( irow:nsize, 1 ), dim=1 ) + irow - 1

        buf( : )     = A( irow, : )
        A( irow, : ) = A( krow, : )
        A( krow, : ) = buf( : )
    enddo
end
```

which gives

```
A( 1, : ) = 0  4  8
A( 2, : ) = 2  1  9
A( 3, : ) = 3  1  0
```

Comment: For why "dim=1" is attached in minloc(), please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670002/using-minloc-with-fortran-incompatible-ranks-0-and-1-in-assignment and also note that minloc() always returns the index starting from 1 for a given array section (so shifted by irow-1 above).